# Java 7 URL Connection Fail

Tags: java, url, ftp

The following code used to work fine under Java 6 (and earlier) but it stopped working after updating to JRE 7 (Java 7).

The URL is an FTP file:

> ftp://ftp-private.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/.fetch/96/4133257873201306969.sdf.gz

Here is the output I get:

> application/octet-stream
>   -1 [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@5419f97c

And here is my code:

```
public static void store(URL url, File targetFile){
    try
    {
    System.out.println(url);
    URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
    String contentType = uc.getContentType();
    System.out.println(contentType);
    int contentLength = uc.getContentLength();
    System.out.println(contentLength);
    Settings.setDownloadSize(contentLength);
    if (contentType.startsWith("text/") || contentLength == -1) {
        throw new IOException("This is not a binary file.");
    }
    InputStream raw = uc.getInputStream();
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(raw);
    byte[] data = new byte[contentLength];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    StatusPanel.updateProgrssBar(bytesRead);
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < contentLength) {
        bytesRead = in.read(data, offset, data.length - offset);
        if (bytesRead == -1) {
            break;
        }
        offset += bytesRead;
        StatusPanel.updateProgrssBar(offset);
    }
    in.close();

    if (offset != contentLength) {
        throw new IOException("Only read " + offset + " bytes; Expected " + contentLength + " bytes");
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
    out.write(data);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    //StatusPanel.setStatus("File has been stored at " + targetFile.toString());
    //System.out.println("file has been stored at " + targetFile.toString());
}
```

The content length returns -1:

```
Area: API: Networking
Synopsis: Server Connection Shuts Down when Attempting to Read Data When http Response Code is -1
```

How do I make this code compatible with Java 7?

Description: As a result of the bug fix for CR 6886436, the HTTP protocol handler will close the connection to a server that sends a response without a valid HTTP status line. When this occurs, any attempt to read data on that connection results in an IOException.

For example, the following code is problematic:

```
public static void test () throws Exception {

.....
HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
....

System.out.println ("Response code: " + urlc.getResponseCode());

/** Following line throws java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
 *  when Response Code returned was -1
 */
InputStream is = urlc.getInputStream();    // PROBLEMATIC CODE
```

To work around this problem, check the return value from the getResponseCode method and deal with a -1 value appropriately; perhaps by opening a new connection, or invoking getErrorStream on the stream.
Nature of incompatibility: behavioral
RFE: 7055058

The problem is definitely with `getContentLength()` method.

With JRE6, this method returns a value, but with JRE7 I get -1.

Comment: Might be worth checking what content-length the server is returning, e.g. by sniffing the network with Wireshark. Also, are you sure the same code still works with Java 6? i.e. have you eliminated the possibility that's it's a coincidence that you changed to Java 7 and it stopped working?

Comment: It works with java 6. It is not a coincident. I am 100% sure about that. See the added content.In this case url is ftp. Not HTTP..

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Java 7's Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) of [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) there are two possible reasons this is happening.

The first possible cause is that the content length is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE. To determine if this is the issue I would use [getContentLengthLong()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLengthLong%28%29) because this returns a long instead of an int and if the content length is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE [getContentLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) will return -1. Also, since Java 7 it is preffered to use [getContentLengthLong()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLengthLong%28%29) over [getContentLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) as stated in the [Java 7's URLConnection Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), "it returns a long instead and is therefore more portable."  If you desire to use both JRE 6 and 7 I would create a Java 6 and 7 wrapper classes to create a set of methods that your application uses to interact with URLs.  Than in your application's start script check if the host has JRE 6 or 7 and load the proper wrapper class according to the JRE version.  This is generally a good design because it prevents your application from being dependent on one specific JRE, third party library or application, etc.

The second possibility is that the content-length header field is not known by the server so the [getContentLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) or [getContentLengthLong()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLengthLong%28%29) method returns a value of -1.  This is why I suggest trying [getContentLengthLong()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLengthLong%28%29) before anything else because it will probably be the quickest fix.  If both methods return -1 I would suggest using an application like [Apache JMeter][11] to determine the header information.  A quick way of doing this is to have JMeter "[HTTP Proxy Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Proxy_Server)" running with your browser's proxy settings set to go to use localhost as the address and the port you set the HTTP Proxy Server for the port.  The information recorded will appear as individual elements themselves and if you expand them there should be a HTTP Header Manager that contains the name of each Header with its value next to it.

Lastly,  you may want to do analysis on the server itself to see if there are any issues.  Verify logs look ok, that all the correct processes are up, configuration's are set correctly, the file still exists and is in the correct location, etc.  Maybe the server is not set to respond to content length requests anymore.  Also, verify if your code functions with JRE 7 on another host

I hope these suggestions will be of value to you and that your are able to solve this issue you seem to be having.  I would also note that you really should consider using a wrapper class and following the notes for each version of third party class that you use in the future so that you follow better practices that are easier to maintain like reducing the amount of external dependencies you have by using wrapper classes.

Comment: Thanks. But, java 7 java doc is irrelevant to this question. The program is written based on java 6. It works fine on jre 6. With jre 7 it doesn't... uc.getContentLength() returns -1. getContentLengthLong() exists only in java 7. The ftp file is pretty small.

Comment: I would never say a Javadoc is irrelevant because whomever wrote the code and Javadoc comment determined that the information is important enough that it will probably needed by programmers using their code (e.g. URLConnection).  One thing many programmers will do is create wrapper classes so that if there are changes your program should be unaffected by the change as long as the wrapper was updated.  In this case you would have a wrapper with the same methods but one would be for Java 6 and the other for Java 7 and to determine which to use do a quick check for the JRE version.

Comment: Hi Matt,Thanks for the comments. This issue has been around when Sun upgraded jre from 1.3 to 1.4. Why jre 1.7 returns -1 for the content length of the file is still a mystery. As a temporary fix, I decided to replace the download progress bar with an indeterminate progress bar.